# DataGridCommandEventArgs Item.ItemIndex = -1?

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, itemcommand

Hello I have a DataGrid, which is defined like this:

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="DG_XYZ" runat="server" DataKeyField="id" OnItemCommand="DG_XYZ_ItemCommand"> ....
```

Now, I in the DG_XYZ_ItemCommand method, I am trying to do this:

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(DG_XYZ.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex].ToString();
```

This gives an error when paging for example, because e.Item.ItemIndex is -1. Question is why? The method look like this:

```
protected void DG_XYZ_ItemCommand(object sender, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(DG_XYZ.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex].ToString();
    ...
}
```

Whats wrong here? Thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

> you paste your complete grid view code
>
> bcz e.Item.ItemIndex start from 0